# jQuery ajaxcall - is there a better way to find the ajaxcaller..?

Tags: ajax, jquery

In my app, I am initiating 30 to 40 ajax calls on load. I got an issue with one of that ajax response..

But i unable to find the where that call is initiateda and called (response).. is there any way to stop the calls and find each of them with their caller details..

please bear with me, in case my question is meaning less.. still i am looking for some idea..

I just looking for the last caller of this screen shot.

[image]

Comment: ajax request are logged in browser console, go through them

Comment: yes, i see.. but how can i find the function which is called..?

Comment: the js function that has made the request you mean ?

Comment: yes exactly. minimum once i know the file, so i can reach the function which is call

Comment: your 30 request are to the same server script with the same parameters ??? you should add snippets of your code patterns, can't imagine why you would not spot the faulty request from console

Comment: I am not say this is faulty request, it is return properly. the issue is it is unwanted request. i have view, and collection each of the section of page has it's own collection one of the collection passing this request.

Comment: add code snippets it's not very clear what you're doing and how you do it

Answer (score -2):

As per my understanding, you're looking for fine way to debug the ajax.  You can't debug the response but it is possible to check the what are the call made using [**Firebug**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) or **`network`** tab in Google developer tools.

Using this you can easily find the call requested to server and remove the unwanted ajax calls.